# SoapUI Groovy script not running in Testcase

Tags: groovy, soapui, testcase

I'm trying to run a Groovy script in a soapUI Test case.

The script does nothing but take the response, extract a value and use it in the next request. The extracting works when I run my script standalone. But, as soon as I try to run my test case I get following error:

**ERROR:**

> java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.String cannot be cast to org.apache.log4j.Logger
>       at com.eviware.soapui.impl.wsdl.teststeps.WsdlGroovyScriptTestStep.run(WsdlGroovyScriptTestStep.java:125)
>       at com.eviware.soapui.impl.wsdl.support.AbstractTestCaseRunner.runTestStep(AbstractTestCaseRunner.java:211)
>       at com.eviware.soapui.impl.wsdl.testcase.WsdlTestCaseRunner.runCurrentTestStep(WsdlTestCaseRunner.java:47)
>       at com.eviware.soapui.impl.wsdl.support.AbstractTestCaseRunner.internalRun(AbstractTestCaseRunner.java:138)
>       at com.eviware.soapui.impl.wsdl.support.AbstractTestCaseRunner.internalRun(AbstractTestCaseRunner.java:46)
>       at com.eviware.soapui.impl.wsdl.support.AbstractTestRunner.run(AbstractTestRunner.java:128)
>       at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Unknown Source)
>       at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
>       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
>       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
>       at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)

Even when I remove all code from my script I get the error. If I remove the whole script the test case runs without a problem. Anyone has an idea?

Comment: hi, could you show your script ? it seems that it has something to do with logger when you call the runner for the next request, maybe your syntax is wrong in that part ...

Comment: My script does the following  


        assert context.response, "Response Empty or Null"

        def jsonString =  context.response
        def json = new groovy.json.JsonSlurper().parseText(jsonString)
        def jwt = json.jwt as String

        context.testCase.setPropertyValue('jwt', jwt)

Answer (score 0):

The syntax of your assert statement isn't correct. If you're testing for null, something like the following will work:

```
assert !context.response: "Response Empty or Null"
```

It's also looks like you're using the assertion to control your script logic, but this is [not a good practice](https://www.baeldung.com/java-assert). An if-then-else clause would make your intent clearer.

Comment: Didnt work. As i said, i also get the error message when my Script is empty.